# Optimise XML update in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

With the error below in mind - any idea how I might optimize the code below?

> The column name 'MyXmlColumn' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'MyXmlColumn' may appear twice in the view definition.

```
UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''play'']/text())[1] with "false"')

UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''eat'']/text())[1] with "false"')

UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''work'']/text())[1] with "false"')

UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''kill'']/text())[1] with "false"')

UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''wash'']/text())[1] with "false"')

UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''home'']/text())[1] with "false"')

UPDATE #tempTable
SET MBO.modify('replace value of (/*[local-name()=''configuration'']/*[local-name()=''sleep'']/text())[1] with "true"'),    
    ToPayment  = 1
```

Here is the soultion: Here is the solution:: CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SBOObject]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @var2 XML,
    @var1 nvarchar(5),
    @var3 nvarchar(5),

)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
        SET @var2.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.ObjectWorld"; replace value of (/configuration/sleep/text())[1] with sql:variable("@var1")') 
        SET @var2.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.ObjectWorld"; replace value of (/configuration/work/text())[1] with sql:variable("@var3")')

```
RETURN @var2
```

END

Comment: I've tried this and the best I've come across is a cursor based approach such as this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/denisruc/archive/2005/09/19/471562.aspx. Alternately, you could shred the data out into a relational table, update it, then rebuild the xml, but that's ugly as well!

Comment: Hoi Elizabeth. Thanks for the Feedback. I have seen the logic. but it will not work for me because the elements I have are quite different. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SBOObject]
```

(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @var2 XML,
    @var1 nvarchar(5),
    @var3 nvarchar(5),

)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
        SET @var2.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.ObjectWorld"; replace value of (/configuration/sleep/text())[1] with sql:variable("@var1")') 
        SET @var2.modify('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.ObjectWorld"; replace value of (/configuration/work/text())[1] with sql:variable("@var3")')

```
-- RETURN @var2
```

--END